# how to use Keras model to predict image?

Tags: keras, siamese-network

I have done the train process and got the model with the .hdf5 format

the neural network that I use is the siamese convolutional neural network.

when validating, the predicted image is a random image from my test folder.
i use this when test

```
test_alphabets = glob('{}/TEST/*'.format(dataset_dirname))

testset={}
for alph in test_alphabets:
    dirs = glob('{}/*'.format(alph))
    alphabet = {}
    for dirname in dirs:
        alphabet[dirname] = glob('{}/*'.format(dirname))
    testset[alph] = alphabet
```

then, display the result with

```
display_validation_test(siamese_model1, testset)
```

the result is like this 
[image]
How do I do the test process by inputting the image I want, then displaying the appropriate image using the .h5 model earlier?

Answer (score 0):

1. You first create your model (keras.Model or keras.Sequential instance) with the same architecture as the one you trained.
2. load the weights from .h5 file `model.load_weights('your_weight_file.h5')`
3. read your image(s). If a single image, make sure to add *1* as the batch dimension.
4. Call *predict*: `prediction = model.predict(images)`

Comment: in pont number 3, can you explain? i dont understand.. please help me

Comment: Let's say you have an image loaded as a numpy matrix with shape *(128,128,3)* you need to tell the model that it is a single image when predicting. You have to reshape it to *(1,128,128,3)* where the *1* shows the batch dimension (here, batch size is *1*). It could be done using `image = np.expand_dims(0, image)`